# Schema/structure of objects returned from RenderListDataAsStream and List/fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, lookup-column, column

Modified `RenderListDataAsStream` request:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/pilotTeamSite/_api/web/GetList(@listUrl)/RenderListDataAsStream?%40listUrl='\''%252Fsites%252FPilotTeamSite%252FLists%252FAssets'\''' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json;odata=verbose' \
  --header 'Content-type: application/json;odata=verbose' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IiIsImtpZCI6IiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL1hYWC5zaGFyZXBvaW50LmNvbSIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vc3RzLndpbmRvd3MubmV0Ly8iLCJpYXQiOjE2NjE0OTQ0MTYsIm5iZiI6MTY2MTQ5NDQxNiwiZXhwIjoxNjYxNDk5MzIxLCJhY3IiOiIxIiwiYWlvIjoiLyIsImFtciI6WyJwd2QiXSwiYXBwX2Rpc3BsYXluYW1lIjoiSW5zb21uaWEiLCJhcHBpZCI6ImZmZmZmZmZmLWZmZmYtZmZmZi1mZmZmLWZmZmZmZmZmZmZmZiIsImFwcGlkYWNyIjoiMSIsImZhbWlseV9uYW1lIjoiZmFtaWx5X25hbWUiLCJnaXZlbl9uYW1lIjoiZ2l2ZW5fbmFtZSIsImlkdHlwIjoidXNlciIsImlwYWRkciI6IjEyMy4xMjMuMTIzLjEyMyIsIm5hbWUiOiJuYW1lIiwib2lkIjoiZmZmZmZmZmYtZmZmZi1mZmZmLWZmZmYtZmZmZmZmZmZmZmZmIiwib25wcmVtX3NpZCI6IlMtMS01LTIxLWZmZmZmZmZmZi1mZmZmZmZmZmZmLWZmZmZmZmZmZmYtZmZmZiIsInB1aWQiOiIiLCJyaCI6IiIsInNjcCI6IkFsbFNpdGVzLkZ1bGxDb250cm9sIFVzZXIuUmVhZCIsInNpZCI6ImZmZmZmZmZmLWZmZmYtZmZmZi1mZmZmLWZmZmZmZmZmZmZmZiIsInNpZ25pbl9zdGF0ZSI6WyJpbmtub3dubnR3ayJdLCJzdWIiOiIwZHRDOEh6MDduUmk3MktzSWxYTzgwa20yYURGcEIxakhRYjR2WElib1BFIiwidGlkIjoiNGEwNzA0M2QtZDg3MC00NTAxLWJiN2YtM2NmYTc4ZGMwMDliIiwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZUB1bmlxdWVfbmFtZS5jb20iLCJ1cG4iOiJ1cG5AdW5pcXVlX25hbWUuY29tIiwidXRpIjoiIiwidmVyIjoiMS4wIiwid2lkcyI6WyJmZmZmZmZmZi1mZmZmLWZmZmYtZmZmZi1mZmZmZmZmZmZmZmYiLCJmZmZmZmZmZi1mZmZmLWZmZmYtZmZmZi1mZmZmZmZmZmZmZmYiXX0.MkFUUKYV6q-waM6K7zlAuPL5yNI4nS3MOavN0wyaIZSvXTrXhvip549iu_suacm8CtvJgcB6xypBd_tWFM-wx4bU7BiVbqTY3R5aStEjVobr1LR4M42eLVPORWCazAuHLAr5Q9rL3a_NtQJuws3gd7NwRMpFqNl5A61CvQHDiDDV0ZlCx8nEIX1unBYzCPn7w43YfbGwN_uE-qcTtMAGjhfIozV9JOInnxDhfap52tIO9NALDznejnxitrDJXtDtymHSN-oWuLONCu0U_G_Ii9bA6Kwj43QPVfgSqINzxqNOkiZon969yEwcr6PR5U_x7CAHKNwQXCvIDykCUFdyuw' \
  --header 'odata-version: ' \
  --data '{
    "parameters": {
        "__metadata": {
            "type": "SP.RenderListDataParameters"
        },
        "ViewXml": "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='\''ID'\''/></ViewFields></View>",
        "RenderOptions": 64
    }
}'
```

modified /list request:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/pilotTeamSite/_api/web/GetList(@listUrl)/fields?%40listUrl='\''%252Fsites%252FPilotTeamSite%252FLists%252FAssets'\''&%24filter=Hidden%20eq%20false%20and%20ReadOnlyField%20eq%20false' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json;odata=verbose' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IiIsImtpZCI6IiJ9.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.MkFUUKYV6q-waM6K7zlAuPL5yNI4nS3MOavN0wyaIZSvXTrXhvip549iu_suacm8CtvJgcB6xypBd_tWFM-wx4bU7BiVbqTY3R5aStEjVobr1LR4M42eLVPORWCazAuHLAr5Q9rL3a_NtQJuws3gd7NwRMpFqNl5A61CvQHDiDDV0ZlCx8nEIX1unBYzCPn7w43YfbGwN_uE-qcTtMAGjhfIozV9JOInnxDhfap52tIO9NALDznejnxitrDJXtDtymHSN-oWuLONCu0U_G_Ii9bA6Kwj43QPVfgSqINzxqNOkiZon969yEwcr6PR5U_x7CAHKNwQXCvIDykCUFdyuw'
```

Partial responses *for the "Asset_Type" field*

```
{
    "Id": "53ffdf04-88bd-4878-90ea-c4681812b733",
    "Title": "Asset_Type",
    "InternalName": "Asset_Type",
    "StaticName": "Asset_Type",
    "Hidden": false,
    "IMEMode": null,
    "Name": "Asset_Type",
    "Required": true,
    "Direction": "none",
    "FieldType": "Lookup",
    "Description": "",
    "ReadOnlyField": false,
    "IsAutoHyperLink": false,
    "Type": "Lookup",
    "DefaultValue": null,
    "DefaultValueTyped": null,
    "ClientValidationFormula": null,
    "ClientValidationMessage": null,
    "CustomFormatter": null,
    "DependentLookup": false,
    "AllowMultipleValues": false,
    "BaseDisplayFormUrl": "https://salamahnswedu.sharepoint.com/sites/PilotTeamSite/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4",
    "Throttled": false,
    "LookupListId": "48629805-4c37-4814-ae45-193b696ebe0c",
    "LookupListUrl": "/sites/PilotTeamSite/Lists/Asset_Types",
    "LookupFieldName": "Title"
   }
```

and

```
{
     "__metadata": {
         "id": "https://salamahnswedu.sharepoint.com/sites/PilotTeamSite/_api/Web/Lists(guid'82c8bdf1-1a9c-4902-a243-db293b13965d')/Fields(guid'53ffdf04-88bd-4878-90ea-c4681812b733')",
         "uri": "https://salamahnswedu.sharepoint.com/sites/PilotTeamSite/_api/Web/Lists(guid'82c8bdf1-1a9c-4902-a243-db293b13965d')/Fields(guid'53ffdf04-88bd-4878-90ea-c4681812b733')",
         "type": "SP.FieldLookup"
     },
     "DescriptionResource": {
         "__deferred": {
             "uri": "https://salamahnswedu.sharepoint.com/sites/PilotTeamSite/_api/Web/Lists(guid'82c8bdf1-1a9c-4902-a243-db293b13965d')/Fields(guid'53ffdf04-88bd-4878-90ea-c4681812b733')/DescriptionResource"
         }
     },
     "TitleResource": {
         "__deferred": {
             "uri": "https://salamahnswedu.sharepoint.com/sites/PilotTeamSite/_api/Web/Lists(guid'82c8bdf1-1a9c-4902-a243-db293b13965d')/Fields(guid'53ffdf04-88bd-4878-90ea-c4681812b733')/TitleResource"
         }
     },
     "AutoIndexed": false,
     "CanBeDeleted": true,
     "ClientSideComponentId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
     "ClientSideComponentProperties": null,
     "ClientValidationFormula": null,
     "ClientValidationMessage": null,
     "CustomFormatter": null,
     "DefaultFormula": null,
     "DefaultValue": null,
     "Description": "",
     "Direction": "none",
     "EnforceUniqueValues": false,
     "EntityPropertyName": "Asset_Type",
     "Filterable": true,
     "FromBaseType": false,
     "Group": "Custom Columns",
     "Hidden": false,
     "Id": "53ffdf04-88bd-4878-90ea-c4681812b733",
     "Indexed": false,
     "IndexStatus": 0,
     "InternalName": "Asset_Type",
     "IsModern": false,
     "JSLink": "clienttemplates.js",
     "PinnedToFiltersPane": false,
     "ReadOnlyField": false,
     "Required": true,
     "SchemaXml": "<Field ClientSideComponentId=\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\" DisplayName=\"Asset_Type\" Format=\"Dropdown\" Indexed=\"FALSE\" List=\"48629805-4c37-4814-ae45-193b696ebe0c\" Name=\"Asset_Type\" Required=\"TRUE\" ShowField=\"Title\" Title=\"Asset_Type\" Type=\"Lookup\" ID=\"{53ffdf04-88bd-4878-90ea-c4681812b733}\" Version=\"2\" StaticName=\"Asset_Type\" SourceID=\"{82c8bdf1-1a9c-4902-a243-db293b13965d}\" ColName=\"int1\" RowOrdinal=\"0\" />",
     "Scope": "/sites/PilotTeamSite/Lists/Assets",
     "Sealed": false,
     "ShowInFiltersPane": 0,
     "Sortable": true,
     "StaticName": "Asset_Type",
     "Title": "Asset_Type",
     "FieldTypeKind": 7,
     "TypeAsString": "Lookup",
     "TypeDisplayName": "Lookup",
     "TypeShortDescription": "Lookup (information already on this site)",
     "ValidationFormula": null,
     "ValidationMessage": null,
     "AllowMultipleValues": false,
     "DependentLookupInternalNames": {
         "__metadata": {
             "type": "Collection(Edm.String)"
         },
         "results": []
     },
     "IsDependentLookup": false,
     "IsRelationship": true,
     "LookupField": "Title",
     "LookupList": "48629805-4c37-4814-ae45-193b696ebe0c",
     "LookupWebId": "58ac9ea2-134f-445c-b589-42a25adc073f",
     "PrimaryFieldId": null,
     "RelationshipDeleteBehavior": 0,
     "UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary": false
}
```

There are differences in the structure of the returned JSON in both cases.

Is there documentation somewhere that specifies the exact structure in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there will be any Microsoft official documentation for this specific scenario you asked.

Check below Microsoft official documentations which will help you:

1. [Working with lists and list items with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)
2. [Fields REST API reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn600182(v=office.15))
3. [Field element (List)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/field-element-list)